# Populate ListBox dynamically in term of the choice in another ListBox in infopath

Tags: infopath, custom-form, form

I have serverals problems to create a dynamic form with InfoPath.
Here is how my Sharepoint lists looks like :

**Places Table** :

City | Adress | Phone number | ...

**Ressources Tables** :

City | Ressources Type | Capacity | ...

The column "*City*" of the **Ressources Table** get its choice from the "*City*" column of the **Places Table**.

First problem : When I create a listbox which get its data from the column *City* of the **Ressources Table**, I get only numbers as choices in the listbox, corresponding to the Id of each City I suppose... How can I get the name of the city from this table ?

Second problem : I have a second Listbox to choose the kind of ressource, and it depends on the chosen city. How can I populate this second Listbox dynamically when I change the city in the first listbox ?

Thank you with advance and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a great way to bypass my two problems here : http://butdoesitwork.typepad.com/but_does_it_work/2011/03/browser-based-infopath-2010-creating-cascading-dropdown-fields-with-no-code.html

My problem was that I filled my listboxes with rules on the parent listbox. And the great way is to fill listboxes with an external connection and apply a filter directly here.